# Table diagram application

Tags: database, diagrams

I am developing a brand new application.  I am wondering if there is an application out there that will help me design diagrams to show the relationships between tables withtout having to create the tables.  I want to get the approval from involved parties before actually creating the tables.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia) can produce diagrams, but might not be quite what you're looking for. Table diagrams are similar to [UML diagrams](http://live.gnome.org/Dia/Examples?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=dia-objects.png).

On Windows, I actually like Microsoft Access a lot for documenting table relationships. ("Relationships" window.) You can hide various levels of detail to make the diagrams easier to understand.  (Liking Access has a lot to do with the fact that it's usually the only remotely appropriate tool I find readily available wherever I work.)